# Можно ли в Microsoft Reporting Service сделать динамический отчет?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Например, пользователь нажимает галочку и в зависимости от нажатой галочки меняется вид отчета(Например, добавляются дополнительные колонки) или отчет статичен?

Answer (score 0):

Можно. В отчетах есть элементы управления, ссылки на детализацию, например, элементы для разворачивания каких либо разделов. Как пример - можно построить древовидную структуру, где корневой элемент будет по умолчанию свернут, и при разворачивании показывать дочерние элементы. Смотрите настройки действий в свойствах объектов, которые создаете на форме отчета.